# Extending base WordPress docker image to download latest wp-content folder

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to extend a base WordPress image (https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/b807f1285869a220a5f72b935901603e5bde8822/php5.6/apache/Dockerfile)

I basically create a script in the Docker file that I want to execute when the container starts up to download the latest wp-content folder.

The base image has the following:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"] CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

I'm new to Docker so thought I could add the following to my extended docker file in order to overwrite the wp-content folder:

```
CMD /application/getwebsitecontent
```

Where getwebsitecontent is just a script to pull down the folder.  The script works fine.

The problem is if I do this, it seems to override the command in the base image so I end up with no WordPress install.  How do I ensure that both ENTRYPOINT and CMD are run from the base and then extend with my own script?

I'm trying to achieve the latest website content being downloaded from backup location on each container start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you overwrite the entry point the original will not work. What you need to do when using your own entry point I that you need to copy everything from the old one into to the new you created. You can see it's content in github repository or when you run it locally and browse it's contents

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but still had problems.  Maybe I need to go back to basics to understand the fundamentals a bit more clearly.  After more research, I was thinking that for my use case I may be better off using shared volumes to get the container to reference that for the website content rather than trying to download the content to the container itself.

Comment: Could you explain one more time what exactly you want to achieve ? Maybe it will help if you took a look in my repository: https://github.com/jacekelgda/wordpress-docker-mysql
This is a simple setup that installs wordpress version as a clean install or uses the`wp-content` you provide in project folder.
If you have any questions about this, let me know, I will be glad to help.

Comment: I want to run load balanced containers in AWS.  My use case is if the container goes down I want to be able to restart a new container as fast as possible but contain the latest web content.  In your docker compose file I see you are sharing a volume with your host.   That seems to be the best approach.  My next task will be to see how I can share the volume between multiple hosts.  Thinking AWS EFS so I can mount a shared volume to multiple hosts.